# Dealing with plus signs showing up when using json_encode() in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, cookies

I am using PHP to save the values of a form as JSON into a cookie like so:

```
// set cookie with search values so we can use jQuery to repopulate the form
setcookie('jobSearchValues', json_encode($form_state['values']), 0, '/');
```

This works great and then on the `JavaScript` side I can use this to get at the values:

```
var jobSearchValues = JSON.parse($.cookie("jobSearchValues"));
$("#keywords").val(jobSearchValues.keywords);
```

Again this works great, but the problem is that when a value for one of the fields in the form has a space in it, the space gets replaced with a "+". So when the form gets repopulated the text field displays like this for example "hi+mom". Is there a better way to go about this? By the way, `$form_state['values']` is a PHP `array`. There are 4 fields in the form that I am setting as JSON into the cookie.

Comment: [`setrawcookie()`](http://php.net/setrawcookie) doesn't apply the urlencoding. If that's workable for your payload is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setrawcookie( '<name>',  rawurlencode( json_encode( $value ) ), ... )` and then manually url-decode & json-parse on the client side (with `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookie))`)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. `json_encode` is not supposed to replace spaces with `+`..

`setcookie` is probably urlencoding it.

You will have to `urldecode` it in javascript before using it.

Try this:

(taken from phpjs)

```
function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

and then

```
var jobSearchValues = JSON.parse($.cookie("jobSearchValues"));
$("#keywords").val(urldecode(jobSearchValues.keywords));
```